# Retrieve the node values from XML file in LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file and I want to retrieve the values from the `message` attributes into a `string` array from the below structure:

```
<Exceptions>
  <Exception Name="Address">
    <Error id="Line1" message="Address Line 1 is required"/>
    <Error id="Line1Length" message="Address Line 1 must be in-between 1 and 50"/>
    <Error id="Line2Length" message="Address Line 2 must be in-between 1 and 50"/>
  </Exception>
  <Exception Name="Email">
    <Error id="Line1" message="Email is required"/>
  </Exception>
</Exceptions>
```

How can I do this using LINQ-XML?

Comment: Which message? All of them? Do you want to concat them all into one string or return an array of all the message strings?

Comment: want to return to as an array of string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string id = "Line1Length";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var messages = xdoc.Descendants("Error")
                   .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == id)
                   .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("message"));
```

Also if you didn't provide full structure of xml file, then:

```
var messages = xdoc.Descendants("Exceptions")
                   .Element("Exception")
                   .Elements("Error")
                   .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == id)
                   .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("message"));
```

*BTW* this will return `IEnumerable<string> messages`. If you want array, then apply `ToArray()` after select operator.

Comment: How to check this with the "id"?

Comment: @VaraPrasad.M updated samples with filtering. If you need single element, than use `.SingleOrDefalult()` operator

Comment: Now if we got other than "Address" and now i want to retrieve "Email" then how can i get. updated question

Comment: @VaraPrasad.M same approach - .Descendants("Exeption").Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("Name") == "Email").Elements("Error")...`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
string xml = "<Exceptions>
  <Exception Name='Address'>
    <Error id='Line1' message='Address Line 1 is required'/>
    <Error id='Line1Length' message='Address Line 1 must be in-between 1 and 50'/>
    <Error id='Line2Length' message='Address Line 2 must be in-between 1 and 50'/>
  </Exception>
</Exceptions>";

var document = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader(xml));
var messages = document.Descendants("Error").Attributes("message").Select(a => a.Value);
```